# PHP preg_match() does not find

Tags: php, preg-match, match

Text:

```
any text..
{{Infobox Ort in den Vereinigten Staaten
| Stadtspitzname = [[Big Apple]]; Die Stadt, die niemals schläft; [[Gotham City (New York)|Gotham City]]
| Bundesstaat = New York
}}
any text..
```

preg_match:

```
preg_match('{{[Ii]nfobox Ort in den Vereinigten Staaten(.|\n)*}}', $text, $match);
```

It returns false not the Text which i want to have. I thought maybe cause the white spaces and replaced it with `\s` but same result..

Comment: What text you want to be returned?

Comment: what  is your expected outcome?

Comment: it seems that it is returning something: http://3v4l.org/7Z1b4

Comment: 1. regexes need delimiters (you accidentally have added them...) and 2. there are several characters that have a special meaning in a regex and need to be escaped.

Comment: There are at least character which have to be escaped: `\{` and `\}`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Capture everything after `Staaten`? Why is the `I` the only character you care about being capital or lowercase?

Comment: i want all the content between `{{Infobox Ort in den Vereinigten Staaten` and `}}`. In this example this: `| Stadtspitzname = [[Big Apple]]; Die Stadt, die niemals schläft; [[Gotham City (New York)|Gotham City]]
| Bundesstaat = New York`.

Comment: @jeroen: to be precise, there are really special characters to escape. The opening curly brackets only need to be escaped when there is an ambiguity with the quantifier: `{n}`, `{m,n}`, `{m,}` *(where `m` and `n` are integers)*. The closing curly bracket is not a special character. The only exception where the two must be escaped: when the delimiters are curly brackets! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/{{Infobox Ort in den Vereinigten Staaten(.*)}}/si', $text, $match);
```

Needed the outer `/` and also need the `s` switch. Take a look at [Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)